# Can't remove certain maps from "Quest Items"

Tags: the-witcher-3

When I buy a map from a Merchant, and then I open it through the Inventory -> Quest Items, it is automatically added to my Map, and then it gets automatically moved to Usable Items.

This has worked fine for the dozens of maps that I bought, but about five of them remain in Quest Items even after opening then. Is this bugged, or are they unique maps? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Quest items are in your quest stash until you finish the related quest.

Maps are like any other items, if you didn't already clear the spot, new maps will go into the quest stash.